# jQuery version update at M2

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I want to upgrade magento 2 jQuery version from 1.9 to 3

do you think is an good idea? 
how i do it for upgrade jquery build-in file who come with magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

No. While jQuery 2 just dropped old-IE hacks jQuery 3 introduced some breaking changes.

You can play a bit with [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/) to see how much the things are broken and what would it look like to migrate Magento 2 to jQuery 3. What is the value such migration would bring?

Just wondering, why somebody would like to use jQuery for such a complicated project as ecommerce system in 2016 at all? :)

Comment: i agree that jquery is not the best js lib for  ecommerce but i think it will be overkill if i use angularJS framework on magento 2 .

Comment: There is support for modren API and promise support.. ii think its pefect for read 3rd party and connect to REST API https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/

Comment: Yeah, I've read those blog post before answering but wasn't impressed at all :)

As to me, jQuery should be buried in Magento 2 just like PrototypeJS before rather than upgraded.

I don't think jQuery+jQueryUI+KnockoutJS+whatever else is bundled too is a bigger overkill than one elegant solution like Angular 2 ;)

Comment: i agree.. you can use angularJS2+ionic2 to build magento 2 app for your own . For now , M2 support only jQuery and i cant insert angular 2+ionic +knockoutJS or whatever because jQuery is required for M2

Comment: >>> jQuery+jQueryUI+KnockoutJS+whatever else is bundled too <<<

this is what is currently used in Magento 2 already.

>>> i cant insert angular 2+ionic +knockoutJS or whatever because jQuery is required for M2 <<<

why? to customize core features you'll have to deal with bundled stack but to build your fancy features from scratch you can pick whatever tool better fitting your needs.

Comment: I was thinking all work with HTTP object to get catalog and customer login and staff.alen Kent say its possible to use angularjs and ionic to M2.. someone do it with magento one(ionic+anhukar+laravrel